# Is it possible to check in all the way through?

Tags: check-in, star-alliance, skyteam

I am an Indian passport holder travelling with below itinerary. Surprisingly, the travel agent shared 2 PNRs on the same ticket.

- Bangalore to New Delhi - Air India (Star Alliance)
- New Delhi to New York - Air India (Star Alliance)
- New York to Jacksonville - Delta (SkyTeam alliance)

Can I check-in the luggage all the way through or will I have to separately check-in at New York airport (given the alliances are different here)?

Comment: In USA it has more to do with customs & immigration than airlines.

Answer (score 3):

1. You must collect your bags in New York and bring them through customs
2. After customs you can either drop the bags at the bag drop right after customs or you need to take them to a Delta check in counter. Just look at the paper baggage tag that's on the bag. If it says JAX they are checked through to Jacksonville and you can drop them right after customs. If it says JFK (or EWR) you need to take them to a Delta check in counter.

Different PNRs for different airlines on a single booking are not uncommon, but it's probably best to check with the travel agent to make sure it really is a single ticket.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar and Traveller.

I have a final question. There is a 24-hour layover in JFK. If I have to manually check-in the baggage in JFK, can I immediately submit them after landing/immigration and visit New York for the rest of the day?

Comment: Maybe: JFK is Delta hub so check in counters will always be open. Technically the earliest bad drop is 4 hours or so but often the check in agent will make an excpetion and take them anyway.